# programmatically print a web page

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am making a program to automatically go to a website and print a page, Can't seem to make it work, I tried selenium chrome driver, problem is it doesn't work. i tried action.sendkeys keys `ctrl + shift + p` to no avail, the biggest problem is print preview pop-up.
I tried sending JavaScript command: `window.print()`, but the print preview in chrome stands in my way, because you need to press enter. Is there a way in JavaScript to simulate the pressing of the `ENTER` key? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after a bit of research, I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6UHjuvI7IE), if you can add these switches: "--kiosk --kiosk-printing", to the chrome driver start, it would automatically skip the print preview prompt, just as shown in the video.
also, I tested this on the latest version of SRWare iron(fork of chromium), and it worked.

If you are using C# to make your program, then there is an easier solution:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintHelpPage();
    }

    private void PrintHelpPage()
    {
        // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

        // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
            new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

        // Set the Url property to load the document.
        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com"); //This is what you want to change
    }

    private void PrintDocument(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

        // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
    }
```

Found the answer in [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this uses the WebBrowser control to navigate to a specific Url, can be a local url or from the internet, and prints it using your default printer.

Comment: Thanks very much, I really appreciate, I struggled today 3 hours with this problem, didn't realize to dig into webbrowswer control of c#, like searching for glasses while holding it in your hand LOL. I pressed "accepted", is this what I need to do? I am new on answering, editing commenting and accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could you use this approach that doesn't require windows forms, worked like a charm for me:
[With C# use Chrome to covert HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324060/with-c-sharp-use-chrome-to-covert-html-to-pdf)

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
var chrome = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)"), @"Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");

// use powershell
process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
// set the Chrome path as local variable in powershell and run
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "$chrome='" + chrome  + @"'; & $chrome --headless --print-to-pdf='c:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\desktop\myReport.pdf' https://google.com";
process.Start();
```