# With C# use Chrome to covert HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, command-line-arguments

I think I'm doing something wrong or this isn't possible.  I am able to run from the command prompt and create pdf fine using the paths in the code below.  For more info the argument string when I use the command line looks like: 
chrome --headless --print-to-pdf="c:\Users\pwtph82\desktop\myreport\myreport.pdf" https://google.com

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
     System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";

        string arguments = @"chrome --headless --print-to-pdf=""c:\\Users\pwtph82\desktop\myreport\myReport.pdf"" https://google.com";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + arguments;
        process.Start();
```

Comment: what does `process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + arguments;` do? And why is `chrome` included in the arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't allow me to do that. But you can start a powershell instance and run it through powershell:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
var chrome = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)"), @"Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");

// use powershell
process.StartInfo.FileName = "powershell";
// set the Chrome path as local variable in powershell and run
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "$chrome='" + chrome  + @"'; & $chrome --headless --print-to-pdf='c:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\desktop\myReport.pdf' https://google.com";
process.Start();
```