# Run Python script with imports in C#

Tags: c#, python, .net

Lets say I have this super Python script that needs to run cv2 in the future...

```
import cv2

def method():
    print("Hello")
    parameter = "l"
    return "OOPS"

method()
```

And in C# something like this.

```
Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Programming\Python\python.exe", fileName)
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But this does throw an error "ImportError: DLL load failed". Alright seems like it is lookin in wrong directories for libraries since I have about 4 Python interpreters. Follows quick fix.

```
string path = @"D:\Programming\Python;" + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"D:\Programming\Python;", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH ", @"D:\Programming\Python\Lib; D:\Programming\Python\DLLs", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
            string fileName = @"..\Python\hello.py";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\Programming\Python\python.exe", fileName)
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Import DLL is fixed now, but another wild bug appeared named,
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

At this point I am lost and dont know what should I do next... any ideas are welcome, have a nice day.

UPDATE:
Deleted all other python interpretors aside from anaconda and one virtual env and tried following:

1. Run Python script from Visual Studio Code with given interpretor, works fine.
2. Run it from Anaconda prompt, aswell.
3. Added manually to system environment variables
   PATH=D:\Programming\Python
   PYTHONHOME=D:\Programming\Python
   PYTHONPATH=D:\Programming\Python\Lib;D:\Programming\Python\DLLs;D:\Programming\Python\Lib\site-packages

So now I can successfully call "python" from cmd, like that and check version, the virtual env is python 3.6 and this is the right one.
[Python is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdSNI.png)
But this is where all the fun begins you would expect "hello" in your console...
[hell incarnate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EIU5.png)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331222/546000; it might help. You're on the right path, but the one thing I see in this answer different is the explicit inclusion of /site-packages/ in the `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Comment: Are you using a Windows machine? If so, you can run powershell, and from powershell, run the python script https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324757/7927820 you have to add `python xxx.py` in `process.StartInfo.Arguments`

Comment: @DmitriyKhaykin Tried that but no luck, but thank you

Comment: @HanjunChen I am but when i call from powershell python it does not even recognize it, but python from cmd is the anaconda one and doesnt work too, however strangely when I run that script in Visual Studio Code with the correct interpreter with OpenCV it works

Comment: The module need to be installed in the Lib\site-packages folder of your python installation. (e.g. C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages). You can install it with pip command from the windows command line (e.g. pip install opencv-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not find correct answer to this problem, but discovered workaround in p2exe or pyinstaller.
Simply call pyinstaller.py --onefile xx.py and create exe file and pass that into process.