# Save EmailBody as PDF file using EWS API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I'm using Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0 to connect to Exchange server 2010. I wanted to download email body to a PDF file in a folder on the disk.

I do not want to use any paid third party to integrate.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution. It is working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324060/with-c-sharp-use-chrome-to-covert-html-to-pdf/53324757#53324757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PdfSharp is a great free library for creating and manipulating PDFs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top), it should set you in the right direction.

Edit: Seems like PdfSharp doesn't actually provide an option to convert an HTML to PDF. I have since explored different libraries. I found that [ChromeHtmlToPdf](https://github.com/Sicos1977/ChromeHtmlToPdf) is a good **free** alternative and easy to use. Bear in mind that it uses Chrome to work it's magic.

Comment: Thanks, Yosef. Can't we do it with native libraries?

Comment: I'm not aware of built it .Net library that can do this.